# Centering Navigation around a centre logo image

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation

I have a navigation bar as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT4TL.jpg

I am using foundation to build a website, the way I have built the nav bar is as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="top-bar">
    <ul>

          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li id="menu-divider">|</li>
          <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a></li>
          <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
          <li id="menu-divider">|</li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>


</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
.top-bar { font-family: 'bebas_neueregular'; 
           height: 150px;
           line-height: 100px;
           padding: 18px;
           width: 100%;
           position: relative;
           text-align:center;
           margin-bottom:10px; }

.top-bar ul { display:inline-block;
              margin-left: auto ;
              margin-right: auto ;}

.top-bar ul > li { display:inline-block;
                   margin-left: auto ;
                   margin-right: auto ;}

 #menu-divider { color:#ffffff;
                font-size: 24px;}
```

As you can see in the picture, the way I have built it means that my center li element (my logo picture) is not in exact center as the other li elements are of different widths meaning they are all centered collectively. What I'm after is the logo in the dead center then the other li elements as they are centered around the logo.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Split the nav into three holding divs, with the outer two being the same width and the middle one being big enough to hold the logo?

Comment: Also, the id "menu-divider" should really be a class, as you use it more than once.

Comment: Unfortunately, you would need to use positioning to do that. There is no CSS way of specificying a particular `li` to be the center and the centering around that item if the `li` are not all equal width. JS could probably do it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play around but I'm pretty sure this does the trick:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYXQpz

Use 3 containers (that means you lose your nav as a ul). Flex them and inside of the left and right one, flex the elements (end for the first, start for the other)

```
<div class="nav-bar">

  <div class="sideNav leftNav">
    <div class="menu">
      MENU 1
    </div>
    <div class="split"></div>
    <div class="menu">
      MENU 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSN9qhGx6NftAepiMOjdGXkcW-UxkO9dtQ4VGRlepyzNC2S8xQCcA" />
  </div>
  <div class="sideNav rightNav">
    <div class="menu">
      MENU 3
    </div>
    <div class="split"></div>
    <div class="menu">
      MENU 4
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Then apply the css. It can be improved but it can help you get started.

```
.nav-bar {
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
}

.sideNav {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}

.leftNav {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.rightNav {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.sideNav > div {
  margin: 100px 20px 0 20px;
}
.split{width: 2px;background: white;height: 16px}
```

Hope that helps. I loves flexbox.

Comment: Perfect, sorry for the delay!